# Adding Percentages to jquery knob input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I'm using jQuery plugin called Jquery Knob
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

To create circular progress bar ,

So here's my code

```
<input type="text" value="90" class="dial" data-width="80" data-height="90" data-readOnly=true data-fgColor="#2ecc71">
```

JS Knob Execute

```
$(".dial").knob();
```

Tried to append ( % ) to value attribute but it's not rendered

```
$('.dial').each(function() {

  $(this).attr("value", $(this).attr("value") + "%");

});
```

Any Suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: it looks like using a percentage in the value will break the whole plugin.  You can probably set displayInput to false, then add an element to the page to show your own number with a percentage, that you can update using the plugins change event.  If you post a fiddle, I can probably help you out if your having trouble.

Comment: What if you used the ASCII equivalent? .... &#037;

Comment: @Rooster Yep , This value attribute must by a nubmer for the plugin to work , i'll try your suggestion and i'll update the question with a fiddle

Comment: @gtr1971 as i said for Rooster , value attribute must be a number to the plugin to work

Comment: @Rooster Thanks ! created a span inside my progress div , hided knob value and styled it and it's working perfectly now !

Comment: can you post your solution ?

Answer (score 38):

As of version 1.2.7 of this plugin there is a `format` hook that you can use to change the way that the number is displayed.

For example you can specify:

```
$(".dial").knob({
  'format' : function (value) {
     return value + '%';
  }
});
```

Comment: Should be marked as answer

Answer (score 5):

Use below code it will work

```
$(".dial").knob({
 'change': function (v) { console.log(v); },
  draw: function () {
  $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%');
  }
 });
```