# How to display units with Jquery Knob

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-knob

I'm using Jquery knob (http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) and it works great but rather than have a dimentionless number displayed in the middle I would like to display units with it ei % or F etc ... How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input.Measure").knob({
        min: 1
        max: 10
        stopper: true,
        readOnly: false,//if true This will Set the Knob readonly cannot click
        draw: function () {
             $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%') //Puts a percent after values
        },
        release: function (value) {
      //Do something as you release the mouse
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used this for a readonly knob - appears to work on initial load, but the graphical indicator is not drawn when the page is reloaded.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443055/overriding-units-on-a-jquery-knob-does-not-redraw-correctly-on-page-reload/21461423#21461423 for a solution to the various redraw problems that the above code has.

Answer (score 2):

As Ben explains on [Adding Percentages to jquery knob input value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18387336/2188595), on the recent versions (>1.2.7) you can use the format hook:

```
$(".dial").knob({
  'format' : function (value) {
     return value + '%';
  }
});
```