# Overriding units on a jQuery Knob does not redraw correctly on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload, jquery-knob

I have a readonly jQuery Knob. I have been able to add units to the numeric display (as per [How to display units with Jquery Knob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955708/how-to-display-units-with-jquery-knob) ), but the foreground (ie. graphical value indicator) of the dial is no longer displayed when the page is reloaded.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input class="knob" id="workload" data-angleoffset=-125 data-anglearc=250 value="{{ workload }}" >
```

( `{{ workload }}` is a floating point Django template value - it is being substituted correctly )

Inside my jQuery ready function, I have:

```
if (jQuery().knob && ! App.isIE8()) {

    // Workload Indicator
    $(".knob").knob({
        'dynamicDraw': true,
        'min': 0, 'max':100,
        'thickness': 0.2,
        'tickColorizeValues': true,
        'readOnly': true,
        'skin': 'tron',
        'fgColor': '#F00', 
        'inputColor':'#3D3D3D',
        'bgColor': '#3D3D3D',
        'width' : 150,
        'draw' : function () {
            $(this.i).val( parseInt(this.cv) + '%');
        }
    });
}
```

`fgColor` was originally set from the template value, but the above code with a hard-coded `fgColor` produces the same result.

Commenting out the `draw` callback works as expected: The knob is drawn complete with a numeric value in the middle and a red colored indicator on the outside arc.
Uncommenting the `draw` fixes the numeric formatting (no decimal points + a percentage sign).  The numeric formatting remains correct for initial display and on re-load.
However the red arc only appears on the initial display - it disappears when the page is re-loaded!

So what is going on? Is `draw` over-riding jquery-knob's own canvas draw method? If so, how can I call the graphical draw part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, sent to me by Sally Maughan (not of this parish):

```
$(".knob").each( function () {
     this.value = Math.round( this.getAttribute('value') );
    }).knob({

    'dynamicDraw': true,
    'min': 0, 'max':100,
    'thickness': 0.2,
    'tickColorizeValues': true,
    'readOnly': true,
    'skin': 'tron',
    'fgColor': wcol,
    'inputColor':'#3D3D3D',
    'bgColor': '#3D3D3D',
    'width' : 150,
    'draw' : function () {
        this.i.val( this.cv + '%');
    }
});
```

The above version uses a new value from the HTML with each reload.
If you want to keep the same value through the reload, then Sally suggests replacing the `this.value` assignment with:

```
this.value = Math.round( this.value.replace('%','') );
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this:

```
$('.knob').val(0).trigger('change').trigger('draw');
```