# Issue Adding Percentage Symbol After knobInput Display in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, web, shiny

I have been attempting to add a percentage symbol after the number display of my knobInput in a Shiny app.

After consulting similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387336/adding-percentages-to-jquery-knob-input-value) that address the issue for directly using the jQuery library and attempting to follow the instructions on the [repo](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob), I thought I could make the change by adding a short script via a tag. Thus far, I've been trying variations of this in my UI file:

```
...
       knobInput(inputId = "population",
                         label = "Percentage of the Population",
                         min = 0,
                         max = 100, 
                         value = 100,
                         width = '100%',
                         displayPrevious = T),
             tags$script(HTML("
    $(\".dial\").knob({
      'draw' : function () 
      {
        $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%')
      }
    });")),
...
```

This does not cause any issues and the knobInput displays normally, but no percentage symbol is shown in the display.  I have also tried nesting the script tag in the head tags like:

```
...
             tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
    $(\".dial\").knob({
      'draw' : function () 
      {
        $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%')
      }
    });"))),
...
```

but this does not help either. Should I attempt a different approach? Or am I implementing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same requirement with [**roundSlider**](https://roundsliderui.com/), check the below demo:

### [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/x10rbfqp/79/)

This can be highly customizable based on your requirement, hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the code that I'm using now that functions as desired. ``` tags$script(HTML("
                              $(\"#INPUT_ID\").knob({
                              'draw' : function () 
                              {
                              $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%')
                              }
                              });")),```

Comment: Actually are you expecting the solution with knob only? Since it seems there was a problem with the cdn so I can't run with this. So that I have achieved the same thing with roundSlider, if you are facing any problem with integrating this then you can let me know. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There is an for that in knobInput **pre=**, and then put your symbol